# passing multiple arguments from php to javascript function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to pass multiple arguments from PHP to a JS function but its not working. Am I using the wrong syntax or any other error. It is not showing any error just simply won't call the js function. Please help.

My PHP code is:

```
function view_members()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $all_members = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM tbl_members" );

            if(!empty($all_members))
            {
                foreach($all_members as $members)
                {

                        $user_status="<a style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"javascript:member_status_js(".$members->member_id.",".$members->contact_name.",".$members->contact_email.");\">Approve</a>";

                }
         }
```

My js function:

```
function member_status_js(id,name,email)
    {
        debugger
        var appr_id=id;
        var appr_name=name;
        var appr_email=email;

        jQuery.ajax({
        });
}
```

When I pass a single argument it works fine, like:

```
member_status_js(".$members->member_id.")
```

but when I pass three arguments it won't work:

```
member_status_js(".$members->member_id.",".$members->contact_name.",".$members->contact_email.")
```

Please give any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you posted the javascript

Comment: If you inspect element, what does the complete anchor tag look like?

Comment: You need to quote your name and email variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes for strings in functions arguments..

```
$user_status="<a style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"javascript:member_status_js(".$members->member_id.",'".$members->contact_name."','".$members->contact_email."');\">Approve</a>";
```

check this line and notice single quotes `'`

```
onclick="javascript:member_status_js(".$members->member_id.",'".$members->contact_name."','".$members->contact_email."');"
                                                             ↑                          ↑
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
javascript:member_status_js(".$members->member_id.",'".$members->contact_name."','".$members->contact_email."'
```